# Fail npm install (at the socketwatcher@0.3.0 install 'node-gyp rebuild')

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to reprogram a dash button to send an SMS to a phone. The task I am trying to attempt is located here: https://github.com/sanzgiri/dash-sms. Below is a copy of the error message I've been getting. Any insight is much appreciated. I'm using Ubuntu version 16 in a virtual machine.

```
rebecca@rebecca-VirtualBox:~$ sudo npm install node-dash-button

> socketwatcher@0.3.0 install /home/rebecca/node_modules/socketwatcher
> node-gyp rebuild

/bin/sh: 1: node: not found
gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('nan')"' returned exit status 127 while in                  binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/share/node-    gyp/lib/configure.js:354:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit     (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-21-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/rebecca/node_modules/socketwatcher
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.6
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-21-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "node-dash-button"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! socketwatcher@0.3.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the socketwatcher@0.3.0 install script 'node-gyp     rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the socketwatcher     package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project     with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs socketwatcher
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls socketwatcher
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/rebecca/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the code is confugure to work with "node" instead of "nodejs".
You can setup a simlink or just run this command. It solved the issue for me.

```
sudo apt install nodejs-legacy
```

Comment: and why would that solve the problem? Provide more than just a one liner...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and nothing would work. Finally had to go to node 0.10.26 on the pi.

Used NVM instead of direct node install.

> curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.1/install.sh | bash
>
> nvm install 0.10.26